# WebAPI 2: is a void response faster then IHttpActionResult?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I was building a method today in my WebAPI2. and came to the question if i should make my method a void or keep it as IHttpActionResult?

As advantage i see that IHttpActionResult can return any response code. What is the advantage of the void approach? is it faster or is the only difference that it always response 200 (or is it 204?).

Does somebody know which one is faster? or if it has any other major difference than the ones that i have named? (this includes the fact that void can't respond anything and IHttpActionResult can.......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every message from an asp.net web api application return an http status code. An `exception` is expensive, so, if you pass this to the web api, the framework should know how to lead with this and change to a `http message` result.

There is no extremelly difference. A `void` action method in web api will return something diferent from `200 - OK` if the code throw an `exception`Actually I think it's even more expensive than a method with a type in result because the asp.net framework need to get the exception and change it to a `http message` as I said before.

If you specify an `http message` in your action method, you know what exactly you are responding to the client (I mean, the `http status code` as least). I enjoy working with `HttpResponseMessage` and create responses with the specific `http status code`.

Comment: see the test that i preformed! Tnx for the great anwser btw!

Answer (score 6):

@Felipe Oriani, you where totaly true.. I was curious so i did the test. 
See this amazing output.

[image: Test shown]

- Void Avg response time is 2.075 ms
- IHttpActionResult Avg response time is 1.651 ms!

So that is a difference of 0.424 ms

This was with the following webAPI code

```
[Route("test/void")]
public void GetFirst()
{
    StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        stringbuilder.Append("something");
    }
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

[Route("test/IHttpActionResult")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSecond()
{
    StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        stringbuilder.Append("something");
    }
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return Ok();
}
```

Also i tried giving the webAPI more work on each request.. to see if the difference stays the same, or if for an longer action it's a real improvement to use IHttpActionResult instead of void?

I set the iteration to 200000 and uncommented the Thread.Sleep(1000) in the WebAPI code

Now the results:

- Void Avg response time is 11.64 ms
- IHttpActionResult Avg response time is 11.11 ms

So that is a difference of 0.53 ms

To which i can conclude and confirm, that what you say is true. And IHttpActionREsult is indeed faster then void. Only the difference is to minor to really notice something. But if your looking for the minor mini optimalisations? this is one of them!

The image below for the result!
[image: second test result]

Comment: Very nice test @spons, it's like a benchmark of webapi resposes haahha... It should be in a week of Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @FelipeOriani If you have anymore differences i could test let me know.. I have the script here.. so it shouldn't be a problem to launch another test :) maybe IHttpActionResult vs HttpResponseMessage ? hahah

Comment: Hi @spons, Yes, could be nice to test `IHttpActionResult` and `HttpResponseMessage` and another type of return for sample, a `List<ViewModel>` returning direct from method, return by `HttpResponseMessage` and another one returning by `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: Another point that could be nice is to share this benchmark code in public in the GitHub, Bitbucket or another website like this :)